# How to convert document file into PDF file

Tags: android

Want to know the procedure to convert doc file into pdf file.

Want to know the procedure to convert doc file into pdf file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The [LEADTOOLS Android SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/android) can load DOC files and convert them into PDF. The toolkit has both native and Java Android libraries that can be used for this conversion. For example, the Java [DocumentConverter](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/doxc/documentconverter.html) class converts the file using a combination of LEADTOOLS Raster, SVG and OCR engines to automatically provide the best combination of accuracy and speed. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)